# 'Count Distinct' and Min(date) in the same pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, powerpivot

Is there a way to have in the same pivot table two value columns, one of which uses `Count Distinct` and the other uses `Min(date)`?  It seems that to have `Count Distinct` as an option I need to select "Add to data model" when creating a pivot, but once I do that I lose the ability to aggregate date fields using `Min`/`Max`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a Measure to the Data model. From the PivotTable Fields pane, right-click the table node and choose Add Measure.  Give it a name (e.g. Min Date) and the function will be something like:

`=MINA([MyDateColumn])`

Repeat for Max Date.  Add the new fields to your Pivot Table.

It works but its a bit of a hassle.  I don't know why they don't just generate this for us instead of showing that error message ...